# Using Tidyverse in R to perform different test statistics according to the class of a column

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics

I have a data frame in R with 5 columns.The first column is the 2 groups that the ids are splitted. The next 4 four columns are answers to a questionnaire.2 of them are continuous variables and the other two categorical.

```
library(dplyr)
# set random seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# create first column with categorical variable with levels yes and no
col1 <- sample(c("yes", "no"), 20, replace = TRUE)

# create second and third columns with continuous variables
col2 <- rnorm(20, mean = 10, sd = 2)
col3 <- rnorm(20, mean = 5, sd = 1)

# create fourth and fifth columns with categorical variables
col4 <- sample(c("high", "low"), 20, replace = TRUE)
col5 <- sample(c("small", "big"), 20, replace = TRUE)

# combine all columns into a data frame
df <- tibble(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)

# print the data frame
df
```

I want to perform 2 test statistics.If the variable (column) is continuous to perform Mann Whitney U test and if the variable is categorical to create a contingency table and perform a chi squared test of independence.

for example for the continuous case :

```
# perform Mann-Whitney U test on column 2, according to the two groups in column 1
test_result <- wilcox.test(df$col2 ~ df$col1)

# print the test result
print(test_result)
```

for the categorical case :

```
# create contingency table for columns 1 and 5
cont_table <- table(df[, 1], df[, 5])

# print the contingency table
print(cont_table)
# perform chi-squared test on the first and fifth columns
test_result2 <- chisq.test(cont_table)
```

But I want this one be executed under pipeline all together.To check if a column is categorical or continuous (numeric) and perform the according test that I want. I want to do it with dplyr package and summarise the p values only.

How can I do it in R ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `summarize` with `across` and a conditional lambda function:

```r
df %>%
  summarise(across(col2:col5, function(.x) {
    if(is.numeric(.x)) {
      wilcox.test(.x[col1 == "yes"], .x[col1 == "no"])$p.v
    } else {
      suppressWarnings(chisq.test(table(.x, col1))$p.v)
    }
  }))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 4
#>    col2  col3  col4  col5
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 0.766 0.882     1 0.619
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Here are two helper functions, which you then apply to the correct columns

```
f_cont <- function(a,b) wilcox.test(a~b)$p.value
f_cat <- function(a,b) chisq.test(table(a,b))$p.value

cbind(
  summarize(df, across(where(is.numeric),f_cont, col1)),
  summarize(df, across(c(where(is.character),-1),f_cat, col1))
)
```

Output:

```
       col2      col3 col4      col5
1 0.7664325 0.8819838    1 0.6192568
```

You can also call those helper functions using data.table, like this:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, \(s) if(is.numeric(s)) f_cont(s,col1) else f_cat(s,col1)), .SDcols = -1]
```

Output:

```
        col2      col3 col4      col5
1: 0.7664325 0.8819838    1 0.6192568
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want to do with the results (how you want them stored). I'm also not sure what you're inspecting in terms of using `dplyr`.

- This answer uses `lapply`, along with an `if` statement to test for the column class.
- I used `invisible`, so that the `lapply` loop list integers would not print.
- I realize that you don't have any factors in this data, but I included the test for factors or characters so the usage would be more universal.
- The results are sent to the console instead of stored in something like a data frame. (Although, it would be fairly simple to modify where the output goes.)

When I ran the code you have written, I received several errors. First, I couldn't run `table`, so I changed the `tibble` to a `data.frame`. Next, I changed the table data to integers, because `chisq.test` doesn't accept numeric values.

```
invisible(lapply(2:ncol(df), function(k) {
  df <- as.data.frame(df)                        # data.frame, not tibble for table()
  if(any(c("character", "factor") %in% class(df[, k]))) { # test for char or factor
    message("The repeatability of the χ\u00B2 test for ", # send results to console
            names(df)[k] , ": p \u2248 ",        # extract col name, unicode 'about'
            chisq.test(table(df[, 1], df[, k]) %>% 
                         as.integer())$p.value)  # extract p-value
  } else {                                       # if num or int then Wilcox Test
    message("The repeatability of the Wilcox Test for ", 
            names(df)[k], ": p \u2248 ",         # extract col name, unicode 'about'
            wilcox.test(df[, k] ~ df[, 1])$p.value) # extract p-value
  }
}))

# The repeatability of the Wilcox Test for col2: p = 0.766432483924744
# The repeatability of the Wilcox Test for col3: p = 0.881983805668016
# The repeatability of the χ² test for col4: p ≈ 0.753004311656458
# The repeatability of the χ² test for col5: p ≈ 0.753004311656458
```

I've written the Chi-squared test name as it's designed (χ<sup>2</sup>) in the console printout, additionally, I used `≈` instead of `=` for the p-value (the 'about' symbol, for lack of a better description).